# Should I actually add nutmeg to eggnog?

Tags: eggs, sugar, spices, milk, cream

Where did adding nutmeg to eggnog come from?

I've tried nutmeg before and can't really taste anything other than nog.

So where did the idea of adding nutmeg come from?

Comment: Did you try pre-grated from a box or freshly grated?

Comment: I was new to cooking so it came from spice container at Walmart

Comment: Or have you always had it with nutmeg (possibly it came with it), so nutmeg just tastes like eggnog?

Comment: Usually buy eggnog at holidays. Family tradition of sprinkling in nutmeg.  But why nutmeg?

Comment: Eggnog, even from a carton, typically *contains* nutmeg, so you'd sprinkle it for garnish instead of using e.g. cinnamon which would change the original flavour.

Comment: Besides, most pre-grated spices tend to go stale rather quickly, if not stored properly (e.g. too warm, too long) they might have lost quite a bit of flavour when you buy them. Whole nutmeg keeps very long, grated doesn't in my experience.

Comment: There's a reason that nutmeg is one of the few spices regularly bought whole... it loses all flavor in an extremely short time if pre-ground.

Comment: It's not really worth adding it to store-bought eggnog. However, homemade eggnog often has two layers: yolk-cream-sugar-booze topped with egg white foam, and the nutmeg is sprinkled on that foam. With that composition, the nutmeg flavor contributes a lot more.

Answer (score 3):

Add it if you like!

As mentioned in the comments, eggnog usually already has nutmeg in it, so when you say you say you can't taste anything other than nog, in reality you're probably tasting eggnog including nutmeg!

If what you add is pre-ground, the flavor probably isn't terribly strong. And even with freshly grated nutmeg, you're probably only adding a tiny bit. So if you sprinkle a little on, it's really more for looks than taste. But if you want to be able to taste it, definitely try freshly grated.

Answer (score 2):

Commercial eggnog virtually ALWAYS has nutmeg in it, so you are just adding to that. While it's easy to grab the stuff, it's worth making your own eggnog if you'd like to raise your 'nog experience several notches.

I can't imagine **grinding** nutmeg at home - that would take a heck of a grinder, and it would be hard to do less than a whole nutmeg at a time, which is a LOT of nutmeg. Of course, there's also the fact that there's an easier solution and I have it already - a nutmeg **grater.**

Rather than using any old grater (and having your "grated other things" taste like nutmeg, which can be persistent) you just get one of these little graters - it has a compartment in the top for the current nutmeg you are grating as needed to be stored in, and you only grate nutmeg on it, so it does not get on anything that you don't want nutmegged. You pop out the nutmeg, grate what you need, and pop it back in the storage part until the next use.

[image: grater image from chickensintheroad.com - not affiliated, just looked for a nutmeg grater image.]

Comment: I wrote "grated" and I'm sure that's what @Jefromi meant, but good idea to show a picture of the "thingy" which IMHO every spice cupboard needs. (And now I'm waiting for the kitchen purists' rants on single-use items...)

Comment: @Stephie Hmm... "Kitchen Purists" ranting - I suggest some freshly ground black pepper, from a pepper mill, blown in their faces. And I wonder how many of them have a coffee maker or teapot that doesn't get used for anything else...?

Comment: ^_^ good to know you have my back!

Comment: Obligatory kitchen purist perspective: a Microplane grater works very well too. It's also good for other large whole spices (like cinnamon), works well for hard cheeses, and I also sometimes use it to grate garlic and ginger for marinades. It's stainless steel and easy to clean so it doesn't pick up other flavors. I'll take it over any single-use grating gadget.

Comment: Yup, unless you're using tons of nutmeg just get a microplane. Really good for grating zest too.

Comment: Don't forget chocolate! I use it for everything! Love microplanes!